# Choppy Droid X2 720p Video Recording

Tags: camera, video-recording, motorola-droid-x2

When recording video through the Camera app to my external microSD card, the video starts to become laggy and choppy, which results in the file becoming corrupt. This only seems to happen when I'm recording to the external SD card and when I'm recording in 720p. I'm using the stock card that came with the device.

Does anyone know what the possible problems could be?

Comment: Any idea what compression it uses when recording? I suppose it's plausible that the card that came with the device is too slow to keep up with the HD video's bitrate. [This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1128566) talks about Samsung Galaxy CyanogenMod users that had similar issues and lowering the bitrate helped.

Comment: @eldarerathis Here is the output from MediaInfo on an HD clip from my Droid X2. http://pastie.org/private/gt2y44vrklrpgjfnppdtow

Comment: Hm, interesting. I wouldn't think that 12 Mbps would be enough to hit the maximum write speed of a class 4 card, but it does still seem like a possible culprit (off the top of my head, anyway). Could also be a bad or low-quality card, I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that that the card write speed is unable to keep pace with HD Video writes on the card. Try using a SD Card with a faster write speed. Also try to use use the same stock SD card in any other mobile with the same HD Video Recording (same bit rate, same resolution) to see if it works there properly. If it fails there too then surely it's a problem with the card only.

Comment: I have an 8GB Class 4 right now (the one the phone came with). I'll try and get this 16GB Class 10 card from Amazon. http://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-microSDHC-Class-Memory-Adapter/dp/B0058GH4U0/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top

Answer (score 0):

well sumit is right, specifically, you get a class 4(4 MBPS) or class 2(2 MBPS) SD card but for HD, Direct copy to SD card, you need better write speed go for class 6(6 MBPS) or if you want it all go for class 10(10 MBPS).

Comment: I have an 8GB Class 4 right now (the one the phone came with). I'll try and get this 16GB Class 10 card from Amazon. http://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-microSDHC-Class-Memory-Adapter/dp/B0058GH4U0/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top